# How to switch between formatters in python logging?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have defined a logger config -

```
logconfig: dict = {
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
                'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
            },
            'withuuid': {
                'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(message)s (message2)s',
                'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'default'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {  # root logger
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console']
            },
            'prm_example_agent': {  # Our module
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'prm': {  # The PRM library
                'level': log_level,
                'handlers': ['console'],
                'propagate': False
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a sample log line in my py file.
`self.logger.info("Destroying fgs " + resource.metadata.id)`.
This is picking default formatter by default. I want to switch to using my own `withuuid` formatter. How can I achieve that at py file itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `logging.setFormatter()` to "push" and "pop" your new format onto the `streamHandler`. Assuming you have a `self.log` that is set up, and say only has a single stream handler you can do

```
# Assuming self.log exists, and is setup
oldFormatter = self.log.handlers[0].formatter # get the old formatter
self.log.handlers[0].setFormatter(newFormat) # push the new format
self.log.info("Very informative message")
self.log.handlers[0].setFormatter(oldFormat) # push the old formatter back on
```

Wrapped up in a nice function that handles multiple stream handlers:

```
def logWithFormatter(logger, newFormatter, message):
    for i in range(len(logger.handlers)):
        oldFormatter = logger.handlers[i].formatter
        logger.handlers[i].setFormatter(newFormatter)
        logger.info(message)
        logger.handlers[i].setFormatter(oldFormatter)
```